# spend time out of your busy routine

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage

I was asked to talk about home made gifts, so I said the following:

> When you **spend time out of your busy routine** on make a gift for someone, it makes them feel important."

I'm not sure if 'spend time out of your busy routine' is correct. How do I say it correctly? If it's correct, is there any other ways to say it?

Comment: looks fine to me.. Is there any particular reason you doubt it?

Comment: Say "spend time ... _**making**_ a gift".

Comment: It's "spend time doing something" or "take time (out of your day/routine/etc.) to do something." I think you're mixing the two and it does sound off to me. In any case, "on make" is quite definitely wrong; the gerund is "making."

Comment: Is there any difference between 'take time' and 'spend time?'